# Excel to MySQL using PHP imports into a single column

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I'm trying to upload an excel file into my mysql database using php, but I have two problems: the first one, i'm getting a "Notice: Undefined offset:" warning for each row of the .csv file, and the second problem, is that it's importing all the three columns of the .csv file into a single one of the db.

My code is the following:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{

    $conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Problemas en la conexion");
    mysql_select_db("kontor",$conexion) or die("Problemas en la seleccion de la base de datos");

    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        $count = 0; 
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $count++; 
            if($count>1){  
            mysql_query("INSERT into stock (nombre,prneto,descr) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]')", $conexion) 
or die("Problemas en el select".mysql_error());

            }       
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'Archivo importado';
        //header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
        echo 'Formato de archivo incorrecto';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at the csv-file ... what separator and enclosure are used?

Excel often uses ; and " for separator and enclosure.

most of the time one of these will do the job:

```
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ";", '"')) !== FALSE)

// or

while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",", '"')) !== FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel usually doesn't like to consistently quote CSV column values; it only does so when it thinks its necessary (at least with some versions of excel). For this reason I usually don't recommend using CSV generated by Excel and opt to just read the excel file in its native format with [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

```
// this is the older version of excel for .xls
// if the file is xlsx you would use PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007()
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5(); 

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

// you should also be using PDO or mysqli for your db interactions
// NOT mysql - this example will use pdo

$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));



try {
  // presumebaly you want this operation to be atomic
  // ie. if any one row fails don't insert any of the rows
  // so we will use a transaction
  $db->beginTransaction();

  // prepare the query
  $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT into stock (nombre,prneto,descr) values (?,?,?)');

 foreach ($sheetData as $row) {
    // execute the insert for a row of csv
    $stmt->execute(array_values($row));  
 }

 // attempt to commit the transaction
 $db->commit();


} catch (Exception $e) {
   // we had an error somewhere, roll back the transaction
   $db->rollBack();

   // retrhow the error
   throw $e;
}
```